# Detection of Economic event on a french corpus

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, nlp, nltk

actually working in a project witch is the detection of economic event from french corpus .
I have more than 10000 corpus that I collected from a newspaper each Corpus talks about a company. for each company more than 10 corpus talks about it .
I need to find a way to extract these information so extract all economic event from a corpus .
I'm using Python 3.7 and mongodb to store my data .
I can't find any tuto talks about this . If you have ideas 
Thank you every one for help

Comment: can you provide more details about your data ? And a small human-readable example of what you want to do ?

Comment: my data is an economic articles talks about companies , Example : Company "A" buy Company "B" the event here is "purchase"

Comment: If you want a script, you need to give us extract of your data. If you want debugging, give us a non-working reproductible example.

Comment: { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c8f6b2e93b48f2c676510e9"), 
    "Corpus_Name" : "Yahoo", 
    "Titre_Pub" : "30 ans du Web ", 
    "Date_Publ" : ISODate("2019-03-12T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "Publication " : "Le Web fête ses 30 ans mardi. L’occasion de revenir sur l’avènement de l’Internet en France ...", 
    "Phrases_Publ" : [
        "Le Web............",       
        "C’est ce  ...", 
        "Le débit .........", 
    ]
}